# Build Python as UCS-4 via pyenv

Tags: python, ucs2, pyenv, ucs, ucs-4

I run into this issue [ImportError numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsASCIIString](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17443166/1391441) installing Python in a [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) environment.

In my case, it happens with the `matplotlib` package instead of `numpy` (as in the above question), but it's basically the same issue.

The answer given in that question is a simple:

> Rebuild NumPy against a Python built as UCS-4.

I don't know how to do this. In [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19575808/1391441) it is said that one has to use:

```
./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4
```

but I don't know how to use that command along with [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

This issue is also mentioned in `pyenv`'s repo [issue list](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/518), and a solution given in [a comment](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/518#issuecomment-199827456). Sadly (for me) I can not understand how to apply the fix explained in said comment.

So my question basically is: how do I build Python as UCS-4 via `pyenv`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing `python` with `pyenv` with `ucs2`:

```
$ export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--enable-unicode=ucs2
$ pyenv install -v 2.7.11
  ...
$ pyenv local 2.7.11
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.11 (set by /home/nwani/.python-version)
$ /home/nwani/.pyenv/shims/python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Aug 13 2016, 13:42:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CONFIG_ARGS']
"'--prefix=/home/nwani/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11' '--enable-unicode=ucs2' '--libdir=/home/nwani/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib' 'LDFLAGS=-L/home/nwani/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib ' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/home/nwani/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/include '"
```

Installing `python` with `pyenv` with `ucs4`:

```
$ pyenv uninstall 2.7.11
pyenv: remove /home/nwani/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11? y
$ export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--enable-unicode=ucs4
$ pyenv install -v 2.7.11
...
$ pyenv local 2.7.11
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.11 (set by /home/nwani/.python-version)
$ /home/nwani/.pyenv/shims/python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Aug 13 2016, 13:49:09) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CONFIG_ARGS']
"'--prefix=/home/nwani/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11' '--enable-unicode=ucs4' '--libdir=/home/nwani/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib' 'LDFLAGS=-L/home/nwani/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/lib ' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/home/nwani/.pyenv/versions/2.7.11/include '"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nehal, your answer is very clear and descriptive.